# How to use Laravel 5 Auth in performing logout function?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem in my logout function. 
Here's my route list:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', function () {
    return "Home Page";
}]);

Route::get('profile', function() {
    return "Welcome back. " . Auth::user()->email;
})->before('auth');

Route::get('login','SessionsController@create'); //alias
Route::get('logout', 'SessionsController@destroy'); //alias
Route::resource('sessions','SessionsController');
```

In my Controller I have this function in logout:

```
public function destroy()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::home();
}
```

Then when I access this URL after a successful login I got this error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 636: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'remember_token' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `updated_at` = 2015-09-02 07:16:31, `remember_token` = GXCcx6tpanPh651DSMkRk3PRWLzyKc3TgYuhz8oPySn2OoESJBrfhbeFpd6C where `id` = 1)
```

I don't know wheres my error.

By the way I am following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msEwmVZ4wp4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#introduction

"Also, before getting started, make sure that your users (or equivalent) table contains a nullable, string remember_token column of 100 characters. This column will be used to store a token for "remember me" sessions being maintained by your application."

You're missing the "remember_token" field in your users table.

Comment: Yeah, I will try to add a new column in my users table.. Thanks for the info. :)